# How to limit the select of x last days results for each device

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to limit to x last days for each DeviceId & Id of this select:

```
SELECT DeviceId, Id, MAX(DateAndTime) as 'DateAndTime'
FROM EventAndMessage
GROUP BY DeviceId, Id
ORDER BY DateAndTime DESC`
```

Example of result:

```
DeviceId            Id      DateAndTime
00:11:22:33:44:55   00D330  2018-05-25 15:41:10.620
00:03:4F:00:10:94   027286  2018-05-11 09:23:26.927
00:03:4F:00:10:94   0351DE  2018-05-11 09:23:13.690
00:03:4F:00:10:94   0351DE  2018-05-11 09:23:09.747
00:03:4F:00:10:94   0351DE  2018-05-11 09:23:01.797
00:03:4F:00:10:94   0351C4  2018-05-11 09:22:47.633
```

In this example I would like to limit 2 youngest records maximum.
Note: 2 should be a parameter I can change.

Correct result should then be:

```
DeviceId            Id      DateAndTime
00:11:22:33:44:55   00D330  2018-05-25 15:41:10.620
00:03:4F:00:10:94   027286  2018-05-11 09:23:26.927
00:03:4F:00:10:94   0351DE  2018-05-11 09:23:13.690
00:03:4F:00:10:94   0351DE  2018-05-11 09:23:09.747
00:03:4F:00:10:94   0351C4  2018-05-11 09:22:47.633
```

Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: depends on RDBMS, see jspcal link, but keep in mind that things like Oracle's rownum don't play well with group/order

Comment: Select top is not what I'm looking for.

I probably not explained correctly.

For each tuple DevicedId and Id I want to have the last x records.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c and above -

```
SELECT DeviceId, Id, MAX(DateAndTime) as 'DateAndTime'
FROM EventAndMessage
GROUP BY DeviceId, Id
ORDER BY DateAndTime DESC
FETCH FIRST X ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: I'm running on sql server :-(